# Cannot Connect To SQL-INSTANCE by Object Explorer: Invalid column name 'mastervalue'

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I Want to connect to new sql server 2019 installation (Developer edition, SSMS.exe v18.10), but i am receiving error below:

```
Invalid column name 'mastervalue'.
Could not use view or function 'sys.configurations' because of binding errors.
Invalid column name 'mastervalue'.
Could not use view or function 'sys.configurations' because of binding errors. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 207)
```

when I open New Query, I successfully connect to Instance, but when i connecting to server by object explorer, receiving this error[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this error connecting SSMS 18.10 to multiple instances of SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition. I also haven't seen any other reports of this... do you have any add-ins or customizations to SSMS? Does your instance have a logon trigger that maybe has an invalid query? Also your avatar reminds me to ask if the SQL Server 2019 installation is on Windows, Linux, or a container? (`DESKTOP-CL1BGBE` certainly sounds like a bad Windows machine name, but it can't hurt to ask.)

Comment: [Further evidence this has to be something specific to your config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80s1X.png).

Answer (score 0):

What is the database setup? perhaps its a case sensitive issue, based on the error you're getting, (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 207), maybe you server collation is not normal?

Answer (score 0):

my issue SOLVED!
My OS is windows 10 Enterprise and my SQL is on Windows (Natively), but the problem was solved this way:

1. Rename ComputerName
2. Restart... but sql not run at all and in logs writen... File 'MSDBLog' does not exist.
3. run sql by -T902 flag and start service and modify msdb filename from MSDBLog-1 to MSDBLog
4. drop -T902 flag and restart service and problem solved.
   Thanks